# Node Express i18n maintainable links

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, locale

Considering i'm using "express", "i18n", "express-session", "cookie-parse", adicionally could use "npm locale" or similar in case need it. Lets say I have routes like this:

```
"/", "/es/" , "/de/"
"/terms", "/es/terms", "/de/terms"
"/privacy", "/es/privacy", "/de/privacy"
...
```

How I should set maintainable and automated links that way , if a user have a language like "es" on his cookie or header ... show them links on pages for "es" version of pages AND also consider set a variable with URL so in case I have to update a link , i will only change one time.

One thing I think of was:

set in a i18n file like "es.json"

```
{ 
  "url_home" : "/es/" ,
  "url_terms" : "/es/terms",
  ...
}
```

then other files will be like "de.json"

```
{ 
  "url_home" : "/de/" ,
  "url_terms" : "/de/terms",
  ...
}
```

I this the right way ? or should I follow any other way recommended ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will say now with few testings , best way would be (and i don't suggest using i18n) create a middleware for urls . I have create this like this:

create a url.json file with:

```
{
  "en": {
      "home": "/",
      "terms": "/terms"
  "es": {
      "home": "/es",
      "terms": "/es/terms"
}
```

then i used on my methods depending on language in cookie (this is when route is **terms** (i'm using dot template) **locale** is my cookie, so in this case:

```
  const urls = require('urls.json');

  ...

  app.get('/:lang/terms', function(req, res) {

    if (req.params.lang === 'es') {

      res.render('terms',{

        // get urls for locale cookie language 
        urls: urls[req.locale],

      });
    } 
  ...
   //more languages
});
```

then in my templates simply:

```
 <li><a href="{%= it.urls.terms%}">{%=it.__n('help')%}</a></li>
```